# Timeout for Type class Async

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

I am relatively new to `cats effect`. We are currently using `Cats effect 2.x`.

I would like to understand how can we apply `timeout` for `Async` Type class.

```scala
def myMethod[F[_]: Async, A]: EitherT[F, Error, A] = {
  val computation: EitherT[F, Error, A] = ???  
  val fallback: EitherT[F, Error, A] = ???

  //How to Execute computation with a timeout of 1 second and recover with fallback ??

}
```

I could do this for the `IO` with `timeoutTo` but not sure how can we do this for `Async`

Comment: Something like: `Concurrent[F].race(computation, Timer[G].sleep(1000) >> fallback).map(/* either to A */)`?

Comment: You probably can just `computation.timeoutTo(duration, fallback)` if you just `import cats.effect.syntax.all._`

Comment: Do try to update from CE2 when possible, the migration is straightforward for most codebases and *dramatically* improves performance, maintainability, and ergonomics. CE2 has been obsolete for almost 2 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both CE2 and CE3 the answer is the same (though the import may differ slightly);

```scala
import cats.effect.syntax.all._

computation.timeoutTo(duration, fallback)
```